# Square root of $ x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My instructor indicates that the $$\sqrt{x^3}=|x|\sqrt{x}$$ It would seem to me that the absolute value bars are not needed in this case because the domain of the original expression $\sqrt{x^3}$ does not allow for negative numbers.

Comment: But $(-8)^{1/3}=-2$

Comment: That is not a square root

Comment: @mrs how is that relevant?

Comment: I misread the term. Sorry

Comment: While the absolute values are not necessary, they are not wrong either. So your instructor is right (and you are too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no need for absolute value since that square root exist only for $x\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x^3}=\sqrt{x^2x}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x}=|x|\sqrt{x}$

Comment: This misses the point of the question--Is the absolute value operation needed? You showed that it is justifiable, which is a different matter.